# Yammer and RequireJS - so happy together? Or not?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, yammer

The only way I'm able to get Yammer's js lib to work with RequireJS is the following ugly, ugly hack:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js"></script>
<script>require = undefined; define = undefined; _ = undefined; jQuery = undefined;</script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.14/require.min.js" data-main="js/app.js"></script>
```

First off: Thanks, Microsoft! Glad you want to share your thoughts with everyone who uses your yammer js lib regarding the identifiers require, define, _, and jQuery (but not $, for some weird reason!).

If I naively omit the first two < script > tags, and try to include yammer in the Usual Approach via RequireJS, placing dependencies on jQuery and underscore, then when the yammer lib is loaded, it **impolitely** replaces 'define' and 'require' in the global namespace. Unfortunately this Causes Problems since yammer's idea of what require and define should do is different than RequireJS's idea.

There is an undocumented flag, window.useRequireJS, that yammer's js lib deinitely looks at; and which looked quite promising! But no - when that is set to true and we then use the Usual Approach, we still get behavior that Causes Problems (RequireJS fails trying to resolve 'yam.$.js').

If I omit the second < script > tag, then RequireJS **politely** does not override yammer's declarations of define and require; but this Causes Problems since yammer's implementation of these functions are not the same as RequireJS's.

If I exclude the second < script > tag and place the initial < script > tag for yammer after the < script > tag for RequireJS, then yammer again **impolitely** replaces the existing global define and require declarations; and this also Causes Problems when require is used later in other code.

My work-around works around all these issues; but c'mon, really: surely this isn't what I'm supposed to do... or is it?

Comment: I also found requirejs hard to use with other libraries and vice-versa. That is why I created a library which is much easier to use and is tested with angular. There is a demo application at the bottom: http://gngeorgiev.github.io/Modulerr.js/

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look here: https://developer.yammer.com/yammer-sdks/#javascript-sdk

Which seems to be the API.

There are a couple of approaches that I'd try, but I'm not sure if that is any better than yours.

**Approach 1: Load yammer into an `iframe`.**

I'd see if I couldn't load the yammer code into an iframe, based on the same domain, then make the appropriate calls through the `iframe`s interface.

**Approach 2: Write a wrapper around yammer**

This is the approach that I'd start with.  If there are only a few things being publicly exported, could you put yammmer into its own function call them export the properties/methods that are needed?

```
var yam = (function() {
  // Copy the yammer code here
  // A local copy of yam would be created here.    

  // This seems to be the exposed namespace
  return yam;
}());
```

Comment: Approach 1: Ugh!! function following form... Approach 2: Hmmmm... Why doesn't it always (or at least optionally) work that way; except instead of 'Copy of yammer code here', you'd have eval(< something we've constructed to handle scope issues >)? Does RequireJS offer this sort of flexibility?

Comment: I wouldn't do it inside o an eval -- I'd physically copy the yammer code and wrap it. Last time I needed to do something similar, I made it part of my build process... quite literally turning a generic module into a requirejs module.  It was something that was complex enough that shims just weren't going to pull it off.